# Delete node and calculate graph theory metrics, R

Tags: r, igraph, graph-theory

I have a 132 x 132 matrix. I want delete each row and column at each step and calculate centrality, transitivity, modularity, degree. I can delete each node and calculate these measures, as shown below.  But I want to know, how to delete each node and calculate these measures in a loop, so I don't have to enter each node manually and calculate these graph theory measures?

```
delete_vertices <- delete.vertices(network, c("node1") # delete one node at a time

centrality <- centr_betw(delete_vertices, directed = FALSE, nobigint = TRUE, normalized = TRUE)
```

Thanks

Priya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(igraph)

set.seed(1234)    # Make g reproducible

g <- sample_gnp(10, 3/10) %>%
  set_vertex_attr("name", value = LETTERS[1:10])

deg <- degree(g)
centrality <- vector("list", length(V(g)))
trans <- vector("list", length(V(g)))

for(i in seq_along(V(g))){
  delete_vertices <- delete.vertices(g, V(g)[i]) # delete one node at a time
  centrality[[i]] <- centr_betw(delete_vertices, directed = FALSE, nobigint = TRUE, normalized = TRUE)
  trans[[i]] <- transitivity(g, type = "local", vids = V(g)[i])
}

centr_graph <- sapply(centrality, '[[', "centralization")
centr_graph <- setNames(centr_graph, names(V(g)))
trans <- setNames(unlist(trans), names(V(g)))
```

Comment: @ Rui Barradas. I have 132 nodes in my network. When I run the code for centr_graph using sapply, I only get centrality values for 10 nodes. When I run the code for setNames, it throws up this error. "Error in names(object) <- nm : 
  'names' attribute [132] must be the same length as the vector [10]"

Comment: 10 is the number of vertices of example graph `g`. With your real life graph `network` what does `length(network)` return? In the code above, you must replace `g` by `network`.

Comment: When I run the length(mynetwork), I get the length as 10. But I have 132 nodes

Comment: @ Rui Barradas. Yes I tried the code and got length as 132. Now, too I get centrality values for first 10 nodes and the rest of the nodes are NULL. When I use setNames to unlist(trans) , I get this error "Error in names(object) <- nm : 
  'names' attribute [132] must be the same length as the vector [10]"